# C# | Linq | SubSonic - Class object

Tags: c#, linq, subsonic

**I have this class/object below:**

```
public class Person
{
  public  string FirstName;
  public  string MI;
  public  string LastName;
}

Person p=new Person();
      p.FirstName = "Jeff";
      p.MI = "A";
      p.LastName = "Price";
```

**Is there any built in in linq or c# or in subsonic that will create an output of this?:**

```
string myString = "FirstName=\"Jeff\" p.MI=\"A\" p.LastName=\"Price\"";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need a `ToString` overload in `Person`. Also, don't expose *public* fields like that. Use [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx).

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string MI { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "FirstName=\"" + FirstName + "\" p.MI=\"" + MI + "\" p.LastName=\"" + LastName + "\"";
        }
    }
```

**(edit)**

Here's your request (but it requires properties):

```
    public static class ObjectPrettyPrint
    {
        public static string ToString(object obj)
        {
            Type type = obj.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                sb.Append(prop.Name);
                sb.Append("=\"");
                sb.Append(prop.GetValue(obj, null));
                sb.Append("\" ");
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
        Console.WriteLine(ObjectPrettyPrint.ToString(new Person { FirstName, = "A", MI = "B", LastName = "C"  }));
```

Comment: Nice one @bruno, but still waiting for more inputs

Comment: you nailed it man!!!
Id="6" UserId="xxx3" SurName="NoBodyx" FirstName="no3" MiddleName="B." Email="x@x.x3" MobilePhone="mobile3" Phone="phone3" IsITIAdmin="False" Password="tHgL5AHoDasddfCmUt0234ffcOuQ" ITIStatus="Not Accepted" ITInstructionID="1" ITIPublishedDate="8/5/2009 12:00:00 AM" ITIDueDate="8/14/2009 12:00:00 AM" ITIAcceptedDate="" CreatedDate="8/6/2009 1:57:58 PM" CreatedBy="ca3" UpdatedDate="8/7/2009 5:58:37 AM" UpdatedBy="qqq" Name="no3 B. NoBodyx" UrlLink="http://www.google.com?p=LLw3ZYXIaEq0BEJM0kjZhg%3d%3d"

Comment: What [attribute] should i use in order to skip certain property by the reflection?

Comment: Nice piece to implement as extension.

Comment: @No Body, To ignore some properties either you can change all the types that use this and implement a custom attribute that will decorate the properties to ignore or pass a list of properties to ignore in the method itself (or some predicate that validates a property). Both require changes in this method.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as for LINQ and C#, not by default.

However, in the Person class you can override the ToString() event to do it for you.

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("p.Firstname={0} p.MI={1} p.LastName={2}", FirstName, MI, LastName);
    }
```

And then you would just call it as follows:

```
string myString = p.ToString();
```

Which will give you the output you are looking for.

Comment: I am a lazy guy, same code as Bruno above. Am looking now for some reflection

Comment: Reflection? Why in the world would you want to do that if all this takes is a simple override?

Comment: I am just pushing the limit here, well your and Brunos idea are simple and straight forward that's why I am applying it already while waiting for some more answer =)

Comment: I then recommend changing your question a bit. Say that you don't want to override and somehow work in the whole "pushing the limit" thing. I still cannot understand it however, but hey, if that's what you want to do.. ;)

Comment: Thanks, because I got around closed to 80 objects =(